Why diffusion of gas in water only depends on partial pressure?
I just learned that there is a type of beetle that could dive in water carrying an air-sac for breathing, and, the air-sac could be replenished by the diffusion of oxygen in water into the sac.
I have two questions regarding this phenomenon, first one might be quite basic that is why the partial pressure of Oxygen remain the same 0.21 atm in water while the concentration is much different.
Also, why do oxygen diffusion in water only depends on the partial pressure difference? Although the concentration of oxygen is much higher in the air bubble than in water, the oxygen could still diffuse from the water to the bubble.
Thanks so much in advance!


“why the partial pressure of Oxygen remain the same 0.21 atm in water while the concentration is much different“.
It doesn’t; it is true however that in water, compared to in air, the same partial pressure of oxygen requires a lower concentration-this is due to the hydrogen bonding in water!
“why do oxygen diffusion in water only depends on the partial pressure difference”.
It doesn’t!
“ Although the concentration of oxygen is much higher in the air bubble than in water, the oxygen could still diffuse from the water to the bubble”.
This is because, when a oxygen molecule is near the bubble, hydrophobic forces force it into the bubble.
